# how to fetch this data in one query?

Tags: sql

I want to fetch this data in simple query

i use

```
select user_id , order_id 
from product 
where order_id = 3 
group by user_id , order_id ;
```

but result is one row for any group

Example input:

```
#user_id  #order_id
1         2
1         3
2         3
2         4
3         1
3         4
3         5
4         1
4         3
4         12
4         6
5         4
```

where order_id = 4 then

Output :

```
#user_id  #order_id 
2         3
2         **4**
3         1
3         **4**
3         5
5         **4**
```

Comment: Whats the table name?

Comment: Can you use a `case` statement within the `Select` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p2.user_id, p2.order_id 
FROM product p1
INNER JOIN product p2 ON p1.userid = p2.userid
WHERE p1.order_id = 4
```

This should be the most effective way to get the data. If this is too slow for you, you should probably create proper indexes on `product` table.

Also note that this will work for specifying one single `order_id`, it will need adjustments for more `order_id`s (`DISTINCT`, to be specific) and a bigger difference for selecting by userid.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT user_id, order_id
FROM mytable
WHERE user_id IN 
(
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM mytable
    WHERE order_id = 4
)
```

Comment: thanks , but This query is slow to large number of rows

Comment: @ArminEsmaeeli you may need an index on `order_id` to significantly improve performance.

Comment: @ArminEsmaeeli: what is slow, what is large, what rdbms are you using, what indexes do you have, ...?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get all records where the `order_id` is 4 or all with the same `user_id`?

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT user_id, order_id
FROM dbo.TableName t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName t2
   WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id
   AND t2.order_id = 4
)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf777/1/0)</kbd>

Result:

```
USER_ID ORDER_ID
2           3
2           4
3           1
3           4
3           5
5           4
```